# Looping through 2 datatable and adding values to third

Tags: c#, datatable

I have created 3 datatables

```
var dt1= new DataTable();
var dt2= new DataTable();
var dt3= new DataTable();
```

Then i loop

```
       foreach (DataRow row1 in dt1.Rows)
       {
          dt3.Rows.Add(row1.ItemArray);

           foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
           {
              var Id2 = row1["Id"];
              var Id1= row2["Id"];
              if (Id1 == Id2)
              {
                 dt3.rows["Name"] = "" ; // doesnt work       
               }
           }

       }
```

As you can see that i loop on 2 datatables. Then in inner loop i check if the records matches. Now if the record matches then i want to update column "Name" on dt3 datatable.

I tried using

```
 dt3.rows["Name"] = "" ;
```

But this doesnt work. I know the reason that its because i again need to loop on dt3 datatable and 
assign values to column in that loop. But not sure how to do it and if there is even more better solution.  I mean we can find id in dt3 datatable and then update value. But not sure how to do it
Is there more intelligent solution than looping on 2 table?

Comment: why use `DataTable` at all?

Comment: @Jodrell so what should i use? I am using datatable because i am getting dynamic columns from sql query. I tried using List but dont know how to make it work with dynamic columns.

Comment: the question didn't mention dynamic data, does the result of your combination of `dt1` and `dt2` need to be a `DataTable`?

Answer (score 2):

The first foreach is not needed. A simple [DataTable.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx) will bring all the data and structure from the original table in the destination table.  Then looping on the second table and [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) on the third to find the matching rows and clear the name.

```
dt3 = dt1.Copy();
foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
{
    DataRow[] match = dt3.Select("ID=" + row2["ID"].ToString());
    if(match.Lenght > 0)
        match[0]["Name"] = "" ;        
}
```

Not sure if this is more performant from the other answers. Need to be tested

Comment: Thats really great @Steve . Will try if it works. seems to be amazing logic. +1

Comment: But this way you would be looping through dt3 at every row in dt2 .. which is (dt2.Rows.Count * dt2.Rows.Count) iterations. This is not efficient on large data, as you only need to loop through dt3 twice to get the job done.

Comment: @Steve Its working but i have issue. If the record doesnt matches then i need to copy some values from dt3 to dt2. Not sure how will achieve it

Comment: Then update your question with this information and add the code of the copy. It is difficult to be precise. A question, how big are your datatables?

Comment: @Steve I wont be getting more than 50000 records

Comment: That's is not a lot of data, but the performance will not be good. If it is possible this should be work to do in the database itself with a storedprocedure

Answer (score 1):

`dt3.rows` doesn't work, you want to change the name of the row that you have added now. This should work:

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in dt1.Rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = dt3.Rows.Add(row1.ItemArray);
    foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
    {
        var Id2 = row1["Id"];
        var Id1 = row2["Id"];
        if (Id1 == Id2)
        {
            newRow["Name"] = "new Name";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably the external loop could be replaced by a DataTable.Copy with a Select to find the match?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   foreach (DataRow row1 in dt1.Rows)
   {
      var row = dt3.Rows.Add(row1.ItemArray);

       foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
       {
          var Id2 = row1["Id"];
          var Id1= row2["Id"];
          if (Id1 == Id2)
          {
              row["Name"] = ""; //maybe works
           }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about,

```
   dt2Lookup = new HashSet(
       dt2.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<int>("Id")));

   dt3 = dt1.Clone();
   forreach (var row In dt1.AsEnumerable())
   {
      var newRow = dt3.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray)
      if (dt2lookup.Contains(row.Field<int>("Id"))
      {
           newRow.SetField("Name", string.Empty);
      }
   }
```

The `HashSet` should provide good lookup performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
    dt3 = dt1.Copy();
    var RowDictionary = dt3.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().ToDictionary(dr => dr["ID"].ToString());
    //replace by Dictionary<string,List<DataRow>> in case ID is not unique and fill it with a foreach loop.
    foreach (DataRow row2 in dt2.Rows)
    {
            DataRow Match;
            if (c.TryGetValue(row2["ID"].ToString(), out Match)) 
            { 
               Match["Name"] = "";
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call:

```
dt3.rows[dt3.rows.Count - 1].Columns["Name"] = "" ;
```